# flash as 3 object layer and dynamic mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask

I have a flash object that is comprised of three layers...
[image]

the top layer 'Layer1' is a layer where a bunch of stuff happens for the program to run (drawing shapes, movie clips, etc) using as3... the next two layers just sit underneath and serve as a background image to the main program that is happening on 'Layer 1'.  I want to programmatically add shapes and sprites and things to the 'masklayer' so that I can update the mask layer programmatically as well...however I can't seem to figure out how to do this...anytime i try to access the object it defaults to the top layer...anybody know?

Comment: Don't do it with a layer. Use a **MovieClip** or **Sprite** as a sole container for all the stuff you want to be the mask, add shapes, sprites and things inside that container.

Comment: Please update your question to show the AS3 code you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

The layers on your timeline only exist in the editor. There are no "layers" in a compiled swf.

To manipulate the ordering of a display object at runtime, you can use [`addChildAt()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt()). This works even if the display object is already a child of that container.

However, it's generally better to avoid that by creating parent display objects at design time. For example, you could create movie clips called maskContainer and imgContainer and whatever you want to have on the bottom you could add using `imgContainer.addChild()`.